# Connection text span with jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I use jsPlumb to display relations in a text. The basis is a text that contains annotations (color-coded). I would now like to represent relationships with arrows between the annotations. The direction of the arrow is crucial. I have now set up a code but no connections / arrows are displayed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your tips.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marmuel/xwosjsa4/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<span style="background-color: LightBlue" class="annotation">Jemand</span> musste <span class="annotation" style="background-color: LightBlue">Josef K.</span><span> verleumdet haben, denn ohne dass </span><span
class="annotation" style="background-color: LightBlue">er</span><span> etwas Böses getan hätte, wurde er eines Morgens verhaftet. »Wie ein Hund!« sagte </span><span
class="annotation" style="background-color: LightBlue">er</span><span>, es war, als sollte die Scham ihn überleben. Als </span><span
class="annotation" style="background-color: LightBlue">Gregor Samsa</span><span> eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand </span><span class="annotation" style="background-color: LightBlue">er</span>
```

**JS**

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {
jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $("body");

window.jsPlumbDemo = {

    init: function () {

        // setup some defaults for jsPlumb. 
        jsPlumb.importDefaults({
            Endpoint: ["Dot", {
                radius: 5
            }],
            HoverPaintStyle: {
                strokeStyle: "#1e8151",
                lineWidth: 1
            },
            ConnectionOverlays: [
                ["Arrow", {
                    location: 1,
                    id: "arrow",
                    length: 15,
                    foldback: .9
                }]
            ]
        });

$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
autoOpen:false,
resizable: false,
height:140,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Delete relation": function() {
        jsPlumb.detach($(this).data('connection'));
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
   }
});


        jsPlumb.bind("click", function (c) {
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).data('connection', c)
                                  .dialog( "open" );
        });

        jsPlumb.makeSource({
            filter: ".annotation", // only supported by jquery
            anchor: ["Right","Left"],
            //parent: "parent",
            isSource: true,
            isTarget: true,
            connector: ["Bezier", {
                curviness: 50
            }],
            connectorStyle: {
                strokeStyle: "#ff0000",
                lineWidth: 2,
                outlineColor: "transparent",
                outlineWidth: 4
            },
            maxConnections: 5,
            onMaxConnections: function (info, e) {
                alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
            }
        });



        jsPlumb.makeTarget({
            filter: ".annotation", // only supported by jquery
            //parent: "parent",
            dropOptions: {
                hoverClass: "dragHover"
            },
            anchor: ["Right","Left"],
            isSource: true,
            isTarget: true,
            connector: ["Bezier", {
                curviness: 50
            }],
            connectorStyle: {
                strokeStyle: "#5c96bc",
                lineWidth: 2,
                outlineColor: "transparent",
                outlineWidth: 4
            },
        });



    }
};


var resetRenderMode = function (desiredMode) {
    var newMode = jsPlumb.setRenderMode(desiredMode);
    $(".rmode").removeClass("selected");
    $(".rmode[mode='" + newMode + "']").addClass("selected");

    $(".rmode[mode='canvas']").attr("disabled", !jsPlumb.isCanvasAvailable());
    $(".rmode[mode='svg']").attr("disabled", !jsPlumb.isSVGAvailable());
    $(".rmode[mode='vml']").attr("disabled", !jsPlumb.isVMLAvailable());

    jsPlumbDemo.init();
};

resetRenderMode(jsPlumb.SVG);

window.jsPlumbDemo.loadTest = function (count) {
    count = count || 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jsPlumbDemo.init();
    }
};


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your entire problem, but I think makeSource and makeTarget take an id as the first parameter, so I'd try wrapping the whole html in a `<div id="foo"></div>` and calling `jsPlumb.makeSource("foo", {...})` and `jsPlumb.makeTarget("foo", {...})`. I also haven't good luck with actually getting it to show up correctly on jsfiddle.